# Find differentiable function such that the Wronskian is $W=C/x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

> Let $q(x)$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$. Find a differentiable and a positive function, $r(x)$, on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the Wronskian of any two solutions of the differential equation $(r(x)y')'+q(x)y=0$ is $W=C/x^2$ where $C\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant.

Here's how I tried to solve the problem:

$$(r(x)y')'+q(x)y=r'y'+ry''+qy=0$$

Since we are interested in $r(x)>0$ we can divide both sides by $r(x)$:

$$y''+\frac{r'}{r}y'+\frac{q}{r}y=0 \tag{$\star$}$$

By definition $W(y_1,y_2 ; x)=\begin{vmatrix}y_1 & y_2\\ y_1' & y_2' \end{vmatrix}=y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'$, therefore $W'(x)=y_1 y_2''-y_2y_1''$. The functions $y_1,y_2$ are solutions of $(\star)$, so $$y_1''=-\frac{r'}{r}y_1'-\frac{q}{r}y_1 \quad , \quad  y_2''=-\frac{r'}{r}y_2'-\frac{q}{r}y_2$$

Then

$$W'(x)=y_1 \left ( -\frac{r'}{r}y_2'-\frac{q}{r}y_2 \right ) - y_2 \left ( -\frac{r'}{r}y_1'-\frac{q}{r}y_1 \right )=-\frac{r'}{r}(y_1y_2'-y_2y_1')=-\frac{r'}{r}W(x)$$
$$W'(x)+\frac{r'}{r}W(x)=0$$
Multiplying both sides by $r(x)$ we obtain:

$$\left (W(x) r(x) \right)'=0 \Longrightarrow W(x)=\frac{C}{r(x)}$$

Thus $r(x)=x^2$. However it seems to be incorrect since $r(x)$ must be positive everywhere. How should one solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Wronskian is required to be $\dfrac C {x^2}$, it is obvious that we must eliminate $0$ from the domain of definition of the solutions (in order not to divide by $0$), and therefore work on $\Bbb R \setminus \{ 0 \}$, where $x^2 > 0$ as you wish. Since it is customary to work with connected intervals, the problem should have been stated on $(0, \infty)$ (or $(-\infty, 0)$, equally well), to eliminate any annoyances. So your solution is nice and clean, it is the statement of the problem that is slightly wrong.

(On a different but related note, please notice that "positive" does not mean "$> 0$" for everybody. For some people, it means "$\ge 0$", with the term "strictly positive" reserved for "$> 0$".)

Comment: Thank you. However I'm a bit confused - indeed, $W(0)$ is undefined, but what it has to do with the domain of $r(x)$? Can't it be that both the solutions and the function $r(x)$ are defined on $\mathbb{R}$ yet $W(x)$ isn't? Regarding the definition of "positive" - usually in our class it means strictly positive (when we want to include $0$ we say "non-negative").

Comment: @user353685: If the solutions are defined on $\Bbb R$, they must also be differentiable with continuous derivative on it, therefore $W$ (which is a combination of the solutions and their derivatives) must also be defind and continuous on $\Bbb R$. Since in your case $W$ is not defined on $\Bbb R$, it follows that the solutions aren't defined there either. (You are giving too much importance to a minor issue.)